# format-number behaviour in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt

I'm working with this OEM-software package (written mostly in Microsoft C# and C++) that uses libraries from Internet Explorer to format XML output with XSLT. Unfortunately, I can't be more specific than 'uses libraries from Internet Explorer'. They won't give me more detail.

The XML+XSLT does not work in Firefox nor Chrome nor Edge, but does work OK in IE. I want to format amounts of currency as EUR 123.456,-. This works:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="euro", decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
..
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($value, '###..###,,-', 'euro')" />
```

What's puzzling me is that I need to double the separators. The last line *should* be this (as per [w3chools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp)):

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($value, '###.###,-', 'euro')" />
```

But that doesn't work. Am I looking at a bug in IE that might be fixed in some later version, or is this 'normal behaviour'?